# Should the [purchase] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, this tag can refer to users attempting to (a) purchase Ubuntu itself (c) buy software on Ubuntu (c) use/package commercial (purchased/purchasable) software on Ubuntu.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes (assuming it complies with the rest of our scope). But... this still isn't a good tag.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, see #1.

---

Therefore, I propose that we burninate the [purchase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/purchase) tag.

Thoughts? Anyone have a reason to keep it around?

Comment: Should we [purchase] burnination?

Comment: I see no great redeeming features to this tag which has been used only 32 times on AU, although I note a few posts where it is the sole tag. Easy enough to remove it manually with such a small number of uses and I would support this.

Comment: Let's remove it manually this week and if it rises again then ask for burnination and blacklisting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a rainy day so I have manually removed all of the tag from across Ask Ubuntu. My apologies to the front page which I spammed pretty solidly :).

With the tag deleted in this way there should be 24 hours or so until the tag itself vanishes and *with no further usage* (and re-creation) it will not be seen again. If it reappears there will then be a case for a formal burnination request.

Interestingly enough [the canonical Meta article on burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/662263) is a little disparaging about *most* burnination efforts but in this case I think that at least the removal of this tag is a good and necessary start...